# Shortest Path between 2 cells in a matrix at random locations

Tags: java, algorithm, path

I am very new to all this so sorry if something seems obvious.

I have been looking everywhere for an explanation. I only can find how t get from one corner to the next. or (0,0) to (n -1,n-1). My issue is, say I have a 4 * 4 grid 16 cells. I have the source as (0,1) and the destination as (4,3). Each cell contains a value, and I need to get to the destination with the lowest cost.

```
     0 1 2 3
     _ _ _ _
0 - |2|1|3|2|
1 - |1|3|5|1|
2 - |5|2|1|4|
3 - |2|4|2|1|
```

I thought maybe try creating an adjacent matrix but I can't see how that works. Is Dijkstra's Algorithm the best way and are graphs the best way to represent this as a data structure?

Is there a way to do it via this way?

Comment: Yes Dijkstra is the way to go, or you can even do backtracking cause grid is very small

Answer (score 0):

Yes Dijkstra's algorithm is suitable for this problem. You can modify the cells to vertices and connect the adjacent cells as edges.

Refer [this](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsDijkstra/article.html) to implement the algorithm

Comment: So ideally I want to create an adjacent matrix for each cell?

Comment: Grid graphs are a type of Implict graphs so no need to define any new data structure, a pair of {row,col} identifies a graph node as for edges just check up/left/right/down directions

Comment: @Photon So the edges are just the difference between two nodes. So say grid[0][0] has neighbours grid[1][0] and grid[0][1]. I need to create an adjacent matrix that specifies the difference in distances for gird[0][0]?

Comment: No what im saying theres no need for adj matrix cause its implict graph, just add a tuple of {dist, row, column} to priority queue, and do dijkstra. For determining neighbours you can declare 2 arrays with values {-1,1,0,0} and {0,0,-1,1} so you can easilly calculate neighbouring cells row and column values with a simple for loop and addition.

Comment: @Photon What are ```{-1,1,0,0} ``` and ```{0,0,-1,1}``` can you elaborate on them?